# Intent.createChooser is multiplying chooser after canceling and share again

Tags: android, android-sharing, android-intent-chooser, share-intent

I am sharing an image with text when I swipe right a RecyclerView item like below;

```
viewModel.shareUri.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,Observer{
        val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/png");
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT," "+requireContext().resources.getString(R.string.paylasimKitapAdText));
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, it);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, view.context.resources.getString(R.string.shareLabel)));
        adapter?.notifyItemChanged(position);
    });
```

Share is opening and then I am canceling. After again when I share , chooser is multiplying? Is there any problem in this code?

Comment: What do you mean by `chooser is multiplying`. Also can you add some more code so that anyone here can try and reproduce it?

Comment: I mean that opening cancelation+1 share chooser after cancelation and again share. They are overlapping.When I press to back I noticed this

Comment: Why is `notifyItemChanged` need in this case?

Comment: Because of clearing canvas after right to left swipe. It is not important.

Comment: Also it is behaving same with button click

Comment: I feel you should add the other code too, the issue looks like something other than the code you have posted

Comment: i think you need to check if value is right 
when value is right you call startActivity
and clear the value
viewmodel.isClicked.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
if (it.value == true){
doSomething()
viewmodel.isClicked.value = false
}

Comment: Yes @JalalKun.The reason is I don't hold and manage with state.